# How to enable `git checkout -b branch` default behavior on VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Previous to Version 1.11.1, when I selected the branch on the bottom left I could create new branches from there.

Now the default behavior doesn't create a new branch, I can only switch branches.

Is there a shortcut to do a `git checkout -b branch` or can I change the bahavior back to what it was before?

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_branches-and-tags)
 says.

> You can create and checkout branches directly within VS code through the Git: Create Branch... and Git: Checkout to.. commands in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).